# Suppose that $f_n\to f$ and $g_n\to g$, as $n\to \infty,$ uniformly. Then, $f_n g_n\to fg,$ as $n\to \infty,$ pointwise on $E$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Can you, please, check if the following proof is correct? Thanks for your time and effort.

> Suppose that $f_n\to f$ and $g_n\to g$, as $n\to \infty,$  uniformly on $E\subseteq \Bbb{R}.$ Then, $f_n g_n\to fg,$  as $n\to \infty,$ pointwise  on $E$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and $x\in E$ be fixed. Then,

\begin{align} \left|(f_n g_n)(x)-(f g)(x)\right| &= \left|f_n(x) g_n(x)-f(x) g(x)\right|   \\&= \left|f_n(x) g_n(x)-f_n(x) g(x)+f_n(x) g(x)-f(x) g(x)\right| \\&\leq \left|f_n(x) g_n(x)-f_n(x) g(x)\right| + \left|f_n(x) g(x)-f(x) g(x)\right| \\&= \left|f_n(x)\right|   \left|g_n(x)- g(x)\right| + \left|g(x)\right| \left|f_n(x)-f(x) \right|  \end{align}
The sequences $\{f_n(x) \}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ and $\{g_n(x) \}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ are real sequences that converge to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively. So, they are bounded, i.e., for fixed $x\in E,$ there exists $M>0$ and $K>0,$ such that \begin{align}\left|f_n(x)\right| \leq M\;\text{and}\;\left|g_n(x)\right| \leq K,\;\forall \;n\in\Bbb{N}.\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\left|g_n(x)\right| =\left|\lim\limits_{n\in\Bbb{N}}g_n(x)\right|=\left|g(x)\right|\leq K.\end{align}
So, we have \begin{align} \left|(f_n g_n)(x)-(f g)(x)\right| &\leq \left|f_n(x)\right|   \left|g_n(x)- g(x)\right| + \left|g(x)\right| \left|f_n(x)-f(x) \right|\\&\leq M  \left|g_n(x)- g(x)\right| + K \left|f_n(x)-f(x) \right|\end{align}
 Since $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ and $g_n(x)\to g(x)$, as $n\to \infty,$ for fixed $x\in E$, then there exists $N_1(\epsilon),N_2(\epsilon)$ such that 
\begin{align} \left|f_n(x)-f(x) \right|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2K} ,\;\;\forall\;n\geq N_1(\epsilon)\end{align}
and \begin{align} \left|g_n(x)-g(x) \right|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2M } ,\;\;\forall\;n\geq N_2(\epsilon)\end{align}
Let $N(\epsilon)=\max\{N_1(\epsilon),N_2(\epsilon)\}.$ Then,
\begin{align} \left|(f_n g_n)(x)-(f g)(x)\right| &\leq M  \left|g_n(x)- g(x)\right| + K \left|f_n(x)-f(x) \right|\\&<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2 } +\dfrac{\epsilon}{2 }=\epsilon,\;\;\forall\;n\geq N(\epsilon)\end{align}

Comment: Your notation can be eased tremendously if you give $\sup|f_n(x)|$ a name, and avoid the big fractions by worrying about shrinking $\epsilon$ towards the end.

Comment: @ John Jiang: Thanks for that advice. Will fix it!

Comment: Since $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge uniformly, your $|\cdot|$ should be the sup-norm w.r.t. $x$. Thus your $N$ should only depend on $\epsilon$ not $x$.

Comment: I think that you don't need the uniform convergence of $f_n$ and $g_n$ for $(f_n\times g_n)(x)$ to converge to $(f \times g)(x)$ pointwise. Moreover, isn't the important difference between pointwise and uniform convergence the fact that you can choose $N$ such that it depends only on epsilon and not on $x$? In other words, you haven't used uniform convergence in your argument.

Comment: @stressed out: Thanks!

Comment: Upon closer look, indeed you don't need uniform convergence. Say you are interested in the convergence of $f_n(x) g_n(x)$ for a particular $x$, then it's just a matter of convergence of a sequence of real numbers, which follows from continuity of multiplication.

Comment: @stressed out: Thanks, I edited it!

Comment: How about now? I hope it's fine?

Comment: Well, still, you haven't used uniform convergence. You know, the problem is a lot easier than what you think. $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a real sequence for any $x$. So is $\{g_n(x)\}$. By definition, $(f_n\times g_n)(x) = f_n(x) \times g_n(x)$. So, your result comes from the simple fact that $\lim a_n\times b_n = \lim a_n \times \lim b_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you have not used the uniform convergence of $f_n$ or $g_n$ in your argument. And in fact, it is not necessary for your statement to hold. The important difference between pointwise and uniform convergence is that the later is global in the sense that the $N$ you find depends only on $\epsilon$ and not on $x$. Geometrically, suppose that $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Then, consider the graph of $f$ engulfed by $f+\epsilon$ and $f-\epsilon$. Picture this like a cylinder of radius $\epsilon$ wrapped around $f$ at each point of its domain entirely.

When the convergence is uniform, after a certain $N$, all $f_n$'s will be contained in this tubular (cylindrical) neighborhood globally for $n \geq N$. When the convergence is not uniform, no matter what $N$ is, some $f_n$'s will not be completely contained in this tubular (cylindrical) neighborhood. This is the geometric idea. In other words, the cylinder wrapped around $f$ might get wider or narrower around some points to contain $f_n$'s. It won't look uniform to us anymore.

In your case, your theorem is implied by the following simple theorem about real sequences:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \times \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\times b_n$$

where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are real sequences. Note that for any $x$, $f_n(x)$ and $g_n(x)$ are real sequences. Now try to continue your reasoning from here.

Comment: Alright, I'll work on that!

Comment: @Mike Yes. It's better now. Why don't you use the same boundedness argument for $g_n$ as well? Your argument is correct anyway, but since the question asks you to assume that $f_n$ and $g_n$ are uniformly convergent, you might want to emphasize that $N$ can be chosen as a function of only $\epsilon$. Even though your argument is correct anyway.

Comment: All $N$'s now depend only on $\epsilon.$ Thanks for your comments and help!

Comment: @Mike It's correct now. You're welcome.